# Reporting Error in TFS 2013

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, tfs, tfs-reports

I have found the following error during report server configuration in TFS 2013. How can I solve this?

> An error occurred within the report server database. This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database. (rsReportServerDatabaseError)
>
> Database ID 6, Page (1:179) is marked RestorePending, which may indicate disk corruption. To recover from this state, perform a restore.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your database has gone corrupt during a restore  action or failed to recover from a disk failure.

You'll need to check the SQL server that's hosting your TFS databases and ensure that it has enough free space, that its disks are in a healthy state and then either restore the analysis and warehouse databases or rebuild the warehouse using the TFS Administration Console.

Make sure you safeguard the last successful backup of your TFS environment on another disk or preferably system before trying to rebuild or restore. Such actions tend to cause massive disk IO and can further degrade the underlying disk.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have checked it. there 16 GB free space available. here, says enough Free space?????   I think this is OK. But I can't find other way to solve this issue??? Can I Restore only Report server database???? is it causes any fault to current database???/\

Comment: The error indicates an error in the current database. It doesn't tell me which one but you may be able to find more in the event log. This doesn't sound like an issue you'd want to try and solve over a channel like StackOverflow if you don't know how to proceed. You need to figure out which database is stuck in restore pending mode and why. At the same time ensure you have a good backup of the other databases, you may have hardware issues underneath.

Comment: i have tried but nothing improved. i have find a solution from Blog that remove Analysis & WareHouse database from sql server then reconfigure it. is it can help??

Comment: An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
Query execution failed for dataset 'dsProjectGuid'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors